# Convergence/Divergence of some series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If I have $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n\log n}$ and want to prove that it diverges, can I use following?

$$\frac {1}{n\log n} \lt \frac {1}{n}$$

- $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$ diverges, but the limit of $\frac 1 n$ equals to zero so the comparasion I think isn't useful.
- Or can I say it diverges because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{\log n}$ also diverges?

And If I have $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{(n)}$ I can use the Leibniz rule. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$ diverges, but the limit of it equals to zero, so I am confused if this series diverges/converges again. I understand that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$ has an infinite sum, but what to do in this case?

Comment: For the first series, you can use the integral comparison (why?). You first point is correct, no conclusion can be made, and your second one is false: if a sequence is positive and tends to infinity, there is always a "larger" sequence that also tends to infinity. And you just happened to find a larger sequence.

Comment: Also the limit of $\sum^{N}_1 1/n) is not zero, this is true for the term $1/n$

Comment: The second sum converges, but not absolutely, right?

Comment: That is correct. Note however, that not all of its re-arrangements converge.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. Even though this was not in my exam today (I got finding Taylor series + other calculus II things), I have passed and also I think I have built some intuition behind this. I hope it will help other people too .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on the elementary inequality

$$\log(1+x)\le x \tag1$$

and straightforward arithmetic.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

From $(1)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n\log(n)}&\ge \frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\log(n)}\\\\
&\ge \log\left(1+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

We can now exploit a telescoping series by using $(2)$ to write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\log(n)}&\ge \sum_{n=2}^N \log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\log(\log(n+1))-\log(\log(n)) \right)\\\\
&=\log(\log(N+1))-\log(\log(2))\tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, letting $N\to \infty$ in $(3)$ yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\log(n)}=\infty$$

and the series of interest diverges.

Comment: (+1) very cool use of $\log(1+x)\le x$ and telescoping series!

Comment: @robjohn Thanks Rob!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, this identity surprised like 3/4 fellow students who didn't expect it in an exam two weeks late.

Comment: You're welcome.  I suspect that the professor expected the students to use the Integral Test or Cauchy Condensation Test.  I wanted to show that neither is needed and that divergence can be established using only elementary, non-calculus based analysis.  -Mark

Answer (score 6):

Your comparison goes in the wrong direction: You need $\dfrac 1 {n\log n} \ge \text{something.}$

Alternatively, you can use an integral test:
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log x} = \int_2^\infty \left(\frac 1 {\log x} \right) \left( \frac{dx} x\right) = \int_{\log 2}^\infty \frac 1 u\, du = +\infty.
$$

Comment: The logarithm in your integrand, made it's way to the numerator.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the comparison was in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

Integral test

$$
\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log(x)}\mathbb{d}x
$$

$$
u=\log(x)
$$

$$
\mathbb{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\mathbb{d}x
$$

$$
\int_{\log(2)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u}\mathbb{d}u=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\log|a|-\log|\log(2)|\right]=\infty
$$

So the sum must diverge as well.

Answer (score 3):

Bertrand's series $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n\ge 2}\frac 1{n^\alpha\ln(n)^\beta}$ converges only for $(\alpha>1)$ or $(\alpha=1,\beta>1)$.

This is generally proved using the comparison to an integral as other answers have shown.

But in general for series of the kind $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n\ge 2}\frac 1{n^{\alpha_0}\ln(n)^{\alpha_1}\ln(\ln(n))^{\alpha_2}\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))^{\alpha_3}...}$

Which all share the same property of converging only if $\alpha_i=1$ for $i<k$ and $\alpha_k>1$ (with $k$ being the last one), you can use the condensation Cauchy test.

The criterion is : For $(a_n)_n \searrow\ \ge 0$ then $\displaystyle S=\sum\limits_{n\ge 1} a_n<+\infty\iff T=\sum\limits_{n\ge 0} 2^na_{2^n}<+\infty$

with inequality $S\le T\le 2S$.

Applied to $\displaystyle S=\sum\limits_{n\ge 2}\frac 1{n\ln(n)}$, it gives $\displaystyle T=\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac{2^n}{2^n\ln(2^n)}=\frac 1{\ln(2)}\sum\limits_{n\ge 1} \frac 1n$ which is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n n\log(2)}
$$
diverges by comparison to the [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), the [Cauchy-Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) says that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}
$$
also diverges.

Answer (score 2):

> The really long explanation of what [robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2323204/272831) and [Gareth McCaughan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2323578/272831) are trying to say for those who like it written out.

Perhaps it will help to see what the Cauchy condensation test says:

$$f(n)\ge f(n+k)\implies\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^nf(2^{n+1})\ge\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}f(2^n)$$

Here, we have $f(n)=\frac1{n\log(n)}$.  A visualization of what's happening:

$$\small\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}&=\frac1{2\log(2)}+\frac1{3\log(3)}+\frac1{4\log(4)}+\frac1{5\log(5)}+\frac1{6\log(6)}+\frac1{7\log(7)}+\frac1{8\log(8)}+\dots\\&\ge\underbrace{\frac1{2\log(2)}}_{2^0f(2^1)}+\underbrace{\frac1{4\log(4)}+\frac1{4\log(4)}}_{2^1f(2^2)}+\underbrace{\frac1{8\log(8)}+\frac1{8\log(8)}+\frac1{8\log(8)}+\frac1{8\log(8)}}_{2^2f(2^3)}+\dots\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}f(2^n)\end{align}$$

It is then noted that:

$$2^{n-1}f(2^n)=\frac1{2n\log(2)}$$

And as we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges, we can see that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}f(2^n)=\frac1{2\log(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=+\infty\\\implies\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}=+\infty$$

> Also note that your comparison is done backwards.  It is **always** the case that you can find an **upper bound** that sums to infinity, but to get results from the comparison test, you need to find a **lower bound that sums to inifnity**, as we've done here.

---

As for the Leibniz rule and the alternating harmonic series, notice that:

$$\small\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n&=\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18+\dots\\&\le\frac11-\frac12+\frac12-\frac14+\frac14-\frac16+\frac16-\frac18+\dots\\&=1\end{align}$$

$$\small\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n&=\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18+\dots\\&\ge\frac11-\frac11+\frac13-\frac13+\frac15-\frac15+\frac17-\frac17+\dots\\&=0\end{align}$$

Thus, we have

$$0\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\le1$$

And as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=0$, it must be the case that the alternating harmonic series converges, as it is bounded and the difference between partial sums tends to zero.

---

On the other hand, the harmonic series is *not* bounded above.  There are plenty of approaches to showing this.  Using the Cauchy condensation test from above, we find that

$$f(n)=\frac1n\\\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\\&\ge1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}f(2^n)\\&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}\\&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac12\\&=1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\dots\\&=+\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, you did so much work with it, thank you.

Comment: No problem :-D Always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another proof, inspired by the usual elementary proof that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. As with that proof, split into sums over integers {2,3}, {4,5,6,7} and so on: $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}$. Within each such range, $\frac1{n\log n}$ changes by a factor no bigger than 4, because each of $n$, $\log n$ changes by a factor no bigger than 2. So our sum is within a factor of 4 of $\sum_k 2^k\frac{1}{2^k\log2^k}$ which, again changing by only a constant factor by taking the logs to be to base 2, equals $\sum_k\frac1k$ ... and we know how *that* behaves.

We can iterate this construction to show that the sum of $\frac1{n\log n\log\log n}$ diverges, and so do the similar series with more and more factors in the denominator.

[EDITED to add:] This is of course more or less the same answer as robjohn's, but with its logic written out explicitly; and robjohn's is more or less the same as zwim's. And in some sense these are all "morally" the same as the integral-based argument in the accepted answer, with its change of variable $u=\log x$; what zwim, robjohn and I are all doing is a similar logarithmic/exponential change of variable while staying in the realm of the discrete.