# Prove series $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove series $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$$ doesn't converge without integral test. I really don't know any hint for $\ln n$. So I understand I have to show $$\frac{1}{n\ln n} > \frac{1}{x^b}$$ where $b<1$. But I really don't know how

Comment: Nitpick: the series should start at (at the very least) $n=2$.

Comment: of cource, my fault

Comment: This is a duplicate of [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323143/convergence-divergence-of-some-series/2323162#2323162).  And one needs neither the integral test nor the Cauchy Condensation Test (which is effectively the same as the integral test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a classic example for the usefulness of the Cauchy condensation test, the rather surprising but easy to prove fact that a positive series 
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a_n
$$
converges if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}a_{2^k}2^k
$$
does as well. Applying this we may examine
$$
\frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n}
$$
which we know diverges.

Comment: One needs neither the integral test nor the Cauchy Condensation Test (which is effectively the same as the integral test).  See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323143/convergence-divergence-of-some-series/2323162#2323162).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)** Use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

$\Big\{\dfrac{1}{n\ln n}\Big\}$ is a positive and decreasing sequence, then $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n} \color{blue}{~\text{converges}} \Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}2^n\frac{1}{2^n\ln 2^n} \color{blue}{~\text{converges}}$$

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/872981)

Comment: @mechanodroid Done!

Comment: One needs neither the integral test nor the Cauchy Condensation Test (which is effectively the same as the integral test).  See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323143/convergence-divergence-of-some-series/2323162#2323162).

Comment: @MarkViola Hi mark. thanks very much! I didn't know that.

Comment: @MyGlasses You're welcome!  I thought you might enjoy that one. ;-))

Comment: Yes. Very helpful actually!

Comment: There is a much more advanced methodology that is quite general called the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.  You're probably familiar with it, but if not, I highly recommend it as part of every analyst's tool kit.

Comment: I studied them about 25 years ago but I forgot now!

Answer (score 0):

we can use Cauchy condensation test if $(u_{n})_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ is decreaisng and $\geq$ 0 then $\sum$$u_{n}$ converge iff $\sum$$2^{p} u_{2^p}$ converge

Comment: One needs neither the integral test nor the Cauchy Condensation Test (which is effectively the same as the integral test).  See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323143/convergence-divergence-of-some-series/2323162#2323162).