# If the ratio test is based off the geometric series, can similar tests be derived from other famous series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The ratio and root test intuitively works by checking the long term behavior of a series $\sum a_n$ as a geometric series. In fact, that's the essence of the rigorous proof of the ratio test.

My question is what if instead of the geometric series, we use some other family of series that we use to check the long term behavior of a series for convergence? (maybe like $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$)

Comment: The [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Examples) converts a convergent/divergent $p$-series into a convergent/divergent geometric series, and converts a convergent/divergent "logarithmic $p$-series" to a convergent/divergent $p$-series (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2563446/13130)), and similarly for higher-order logarithmic $p$-series that are called *generalized Bertrand series* -- each application of the Cauchy condensation test removes one "logarithmic level" -- see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2323159/13130).

Comment: Here is a general criterion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test See also this (only in German...): https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriterium_von_Raabe